# 500 error navigating to Zend application using domain name

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, dns

I have a Zend application hosted on godaddy with a domain name pointed to the subfolder holding the application which results in a 500 server error when using the domain name. I am using a Linux host and the path to the public folder is /Subfolder Name/public, which is where the domain name is pointed. What is confusing is that when I navigate to the site with:
Host IP address/Subfolder path there is no problem. When using the domain name for navigation the following is produced in the error logs:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

After looking around it seems likely this is a .htaccess issue. The .htaccess file in my public folder is below:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    # The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
    # exists, simply serve it.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    # The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
    # condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
    # mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
    # allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
    # in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
    # fits all solution.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule is *supposed to* prevent the internal redirects, so it's probably the case that the last rewrite that routes to `index.php` is wrong. Try changing it to simplify the routing from:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

If the `index.php` is in another path, then just change the `/index.php` so that it points to the right place.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. If you would not mind explaining I am curious what is going on in this file and why the fix worked.

Comment: @mjtieman55 I'm not exactly sure what's going on there, but it's attempting to extract a base URI and appending that in front of the `index.php`. The comments sort of explain it.